# Calling to function in another process

Tags: c#, winapi, function, code-injection

I'm trying to call the Open Video function in DivXLand program. What I want to do is to make a built in subtitles using DivXLand program with C#.

First, I want to load up DivXLand, then, I want to click on File->Open video then on File->Open text or subtitle...

I wanted to go with the WinAPI approach but I failed to navigate to the menu items.
Then, I thought it would be easier if I could just call the functions that select the video file and the subtitles file.

My question is:
1. How can I call that OpenVideo function?
2. How can I find the functions that DivXLand uses?

If you want to test it yourself you can download DivXLand for free and it only weights 600k-700k or something.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Which DivxLand software are you talking about?

Comment: I think by answering your another question, this one is also somehow solved.

Comment: Not really solved. I'm still interested in understanding this method too.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might want to look into [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for controlling the other application. Calling into the other program will be difficult at best, if not impossible as the program may not export anything that you could call.

Comment: I want to be able to execute this from my C# project.

Answer (score 0):

If it was a .NET application, then it was not so difficult. But for native applications, it is extremely hard to find and invoke those methods. In my opinion the simplest way is to automate the UI by finding control handles, sending messages, reading/writing controls' values and sending keystrokes. The process involves some tricks, but it is not that hard.